# Spark too many small S3 files with DDB stream

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am designing solution that reads DDB stream and write to S3 using Lambda for writing to S3 datalake

I will be reading max batch size of 10,000 changes in a batch window of like 2 minutes. Based on the velocity of change in the DB, my design might also create small S3 Files. I am seeing customers having issues with Spark not working properly with small S3 files. I am wondering how this common this issue is?